# YouTube Video Event

Tags: java, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am searching for an event which is triggered if a new YouTube video on a specific channel is published. Is there something like that? I searched a little bit in the API but couldn’t find something like that.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this, https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications

Comment: If I knew how... :D this app is strange, maybe on pc I find a way :) (never knew this is possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications

Essentially you need to do the following as per the documentation:

- Set up a callback server that can handle incoming Atom feed notifications.
- Use the Google hub to subscribe to receive push notifications.
- Process notifications sent to your callback server.

If you had a working example, I'd attempt to help you further.